# Copy user provided text in a specific format to clipboard

Tags: copy

I'm trying to write a bIt  of code that will streamline work for me and my Co workers. We have to repeatedly write up a note to put into our computer system saying that a client account "termed xx/xx/xxxx. No contact grp, no alt id"  very rarely does anything but the date change in the note. We only have access to IE8.  What I'd like to do is just enter the date into a text box and hit a copy button and have the note populate to the clipboard. 
Is this even possible? My googlefu has failed me. 
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is have another text field, elsewhere on the page, that generates all the text you want, and have that in focus when they copy.

Something like,

```
       function putThisTogether()
      {
          document.getElementById("fullText").value = document.getElementById("fullText").value + " " + document.getElementById("textIs").value;
          document.getElementById("fullText").focus();
document.getElementById("fullText").select();

}



<input type="Text" id="textIs" size="90" value="text will appear here" onblur="putThisTogether()" ><br />
<input type="Text" id="fullText" size="90" value="Date, or whatever" >
```

That will add whatever they typed to whatever you already had, and set the focus to the other field.  When they press COPY, they will be copying that.